# What is the minimum clearance I need to set between two tracks with voltage difference 36 V

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, design-rules

What is the minimum clearance I need to set between two tracks with voltage difference of 36 V.
External traces, given that solder mask is applied on the board if it matter in calculation. And is there any other variables that we have to take into consideration?
[image]

Comment: I forget the IPC rules but if conductors are sealed in epoxy mask , 250V/mm is safe from experience and protect if high power in case of fault. The breakdown rating might be 5kV/mm

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience. yes there will be solder mask on top of the board. I have a question, are we mainly trying to protect the dielectric between the traces from conducting? or are there other considerations?

Comment: all insulators are dielectrics and all have a breakdown voltage (BDV) in kV/mm.  But air surfaces get contaminated so we use “creepage” values due to dust and %RH factors which can reduce air by an order of magnitude.  You make look up all different materials for dielectric BDV. So yes all interfaces. But for power-gnd we try to use the smallest to add more capacitance which has  low ESR(good)

Comment: I am not sure I got the last part regarding the power-gnd capacitance.

Comment: There is a company that specializes in very smooth copper and thin prepreg layer to maximum distributed capacitance. You can model this on Saturn PCB design.exe

Comment: Most Electric Vehicle Motor Controller which operates at 36V have similar 36V & GND tracks very near but they keep at least 10mil,0.254mm separation due to the fact that if a high amount of current will flow the tracks, they will become hot and elongate and distance between them will decrease. in your case distance is ok.

Comment: Trace clearance is dependent on isolation class, contamination, operation height, .... but for up to 50V the standards say ~1,5mm for normal use and ~2mm for harder constraints.

Comment: 0.6 mm or even less can work good? given that it is 36 V not 50, and the traces are coated with solder mask.